# Different GoogleService-Info.plist files for dev and prod for ios and android in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, google-signin

I am using google sign-in in an app using [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin). I have a dev and a prod google API project set up in the backend.

I want to use the separate GoogleService-Info.plist for dev and prod in my react-native app.

How can I configure  GoogleService-Info.plist depending upon the environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have configured your project with https://console.developers.google.com
There is no need to configure anything in your code.

For **ANDROID** by default, you can set up 3 environments

1. DEV
2. RELEASE
3. Google Play(Production)

ANDROID provides separate SHA-1 Keys for the above-mentioned environemnts.
With these SHA-1 keys, you can create 3 Oauth projects. Now you have 3 Oauth google projects that you can configure with 3 separate branches(dev, release, prod) of your project.

FOR **IOS**

You can create as many Oauth google projects as you like.
Just keep the GoogleService-Info.plist of your Oauth google project depending upon the environment in the ios folder at the time of making the build.

Answer (score 0):

You need to config based on your env.

```
NSString *firebasePlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info" ofType:@"plist"];

#if DEV
    firebasePlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info-DEV" ofType:@"plist"];
#endif

FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:firebasePlist];
[FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
```

Comment: can you send me details example please